# Include HTML files in MS Word

Tags: html, ms-word

is it possible to include normal HTML files in Word, so that they are shown in correct style etc. and not as normal text files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible, if you right click any html file and open it in Word using 'Open With' option, then it will be there inside the Word.